# Javascript Regular Expressions /ab*c/

Tags: javascript

**var regex = /ab*c/;
console.log(regex.test('abac'));**

This javascript regular expression outputs true to the console with the given input. But from my understanding of Regular expressions,it is supposed to output false. When I change the 'a' to any other alphabet it returns false.

I expect the pattern to match : **ac, abc, abbc, abbbc** etc. 
Please can someone help with an explanation or is this a bug in the javascript compiler? I tried the same code in java and python and they return false.

Comment: This is not a bug; the pattern is indeed matching **ac** in your test string

Comment: Your regex doesn't enforce the start or end of the matched piece, so since `/ab*c/` matches the substring `"ac"`, it returns true. Try enforcing the start and endpoints. EG: `/^ab*c$/` instead.

Comment: and abac contains ac, isn't it?

Comment: I'd also point out that python's regex works exactly the same; `re.search('ab*c', 'abac')` returns a match, so it's not clear to me how you got that this returns false in python

Comment: Just as a friendly tip: blaming JavaScript's compiler should be a really last resort...

Comment: Thanks. I get it now. I think it was a logic error on my side. After revising the Java docs, I realized the matcher enforces end and start of string. So for this string('ab*c'), the java compiler will only return true if the string matches the whole regex pattern.I enforced the start and end of input in javascript (/^ab*c$/) and it returns false. And I am okay with the python now. Thanks for the comments

Comment: And thanks for the friendly tip..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*" means "Matches the preceding expression 0 or more times". So it will match any string that contains "ac" (b 0 times in this case)